# Importing database from file without triggering Firebase functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase db and I implemented some functions. For example, when `/lists/{list_id}/` is created, a function automatically sets `/lists/{list_id}/created_on` to the current timestamp.

I've just realized that when I import a database from a file, Firebase still runs all these functions, so the `created_on` for ALL the lists is set to the current timestamp.

I also have functions that send emails upon addition of stuff, and I definitely don't want them to fire either.

How do I avoid it? I want to restore the db from a file without triggering any functions.

Comment: Found an ugly workaround: go to https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/ and delete all the functions. The import the db from file, then redeploy. It's ugly because: 1) there's a high chance that I'll forget to do it when I really need to restore the db in the future. 2) it requires to redeploy: disable/enable would be much easier... Is there a better way??

Answer (score 0):

Are you restoring from a completely clean state where no actual users are using the project?  In that case, simply undeploy all your functions by deploying an empty index.js, perform your import, then deploy all your functions again.  This should be achievable all with the Firebase CLI.

If you have records to import while the product has legitimate use that you don't want to impact, it wouldn't be advisable to turn off your functions for any amount of time.  Instead, you could massage your import data to add a child that indicates that a particular field is to be exempt from processing by whatever functions you have, and have those functions check to see if that child exists.  You can delete that child later if it gets in the way.

Comment: I restored the database from a backup file due to a corruption (which may happen again in the future). So adding a 'child-flag' won't work for me. I thought of adding a function that will be triggered on creation of a specific key (e.g. /internal/make_sure_functions_are_off), and will delete the whole db and replace it with a message "you forgot to delete the functions before restoring the db". This special key will always be in the db. This way, if I ever restore again and forget to delete the functions, I'll get a helpful reminder. But it's only a workaround, not a real solution...